# Mysql truncates the data

Tags: mysql

I can't upload data to mysql with csv upload.

I got this error now:
[image]

It says duplicate entry for '7'. but it is not 7 actually. it is 907 in the csv file I'm trying to upload. Mysql takes only 7 of 907 for some reason. How can i solve this problem? please. thanks.
      -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
        -- version 4.6.4
        -- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
        --
        -- Host: 127.0.0.1
        -- Generation Time: Nov 04, 2018 at 11:27 AM
        -- Server version: 5.7.14
        -- PHP Version: 5.6.25

```
    SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
    SET time_zone = "+00:00";


    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
    /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

    --
    -- Database: `mdb`
    --

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `ttb`
    --

    CREATE TABLE `ttb` (
      `Week` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `Sside` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Schange` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `SRep` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
      `SRepC` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Opp` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `RuRpt` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `RaRpt` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `DuRpt` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `DaRpt` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Dist1` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Dist2` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Dist3` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Dist4` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Dist5` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Distin` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Sint` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Svar` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Sdev` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Smean` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Smedian` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Rerng` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Bmedian` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Opp1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Opp2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and this is the beginning of CSV file that I want to upload:

```
906,24/10/2018,14,B,,7,,,,,x,4,,,2,3,4,1,2,1,1,1,0.3,,3,1
905,17/10/2018,5,A,,5,,,R1,S1,2x,,3,,2,3,1,4,1,2,1,1,,3,3,2
```

Comment: Why don't you specify the column names? I assume your first column is unique id.

Comment: Doesn't look like 907 to me. Can you add a sample of your csv file as text to the question together with your table definition. And how are you loading - via a load statement or via phpmyadmin(if that's what it is) import function.

Comment: I load with CSV function from import in phpmyadmin

Comment: Is your row really terminated by comma or is that a typo , and can you confirm the csv file only contains 7 columns.And are you on linux or windows?

Comment: It is not terminated with comma. I only put the beginning of the csv file. My csv structure is ok, I generate it from excel, and it used to work before. I started having this problem now.

Comment: Surely it cannot be that difficult to provide a few rows of csv file?

Comment: I updated my post with csv data example.

Comment: The sample data loads without problem (other than the date which is not valid format) using phpmyadmin's import function on a linux box. If you are having problems it's down to data or the import options you select.

Comment: If you say that a row with "907" is causing the problem, why would you include the rows "905" and "906" as a sample, but not row "907" (which should probably be the first row if the file is sorted by that column)? My best guess so far would be: you made an error in your csv file and *actually* stored row "907" as row "7" by accident. Just scroll down in your file until you get to 7, you will probably find two.